# Won't continue executing statement on ACTION_DOWN

Tags: java, android, events, ontouchlistener

I am making a lunar lander game for my assignment

i have a button and set an onTouchListener to it (not onClick)
when the button is down or ACTION_DOWN the rocket flies up and stops acceleration on ACTION_UP.

currently it is only performing this once on ACTION_DOWN so it is behaving like an onClick button.

any help would be appreciated

- gView is an instance of the game class where all the magic happens
- gView.mainThruster() calls the method in the game class that causes the spaceship to fly upwards e.g Y -= 10;

  ```
  mThrust = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainThrustBtn);    
  mThrust.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

      if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
          if(fuel > 0){

                gView.checkFuel(fuel);
            gView.mainThruster();
            mThrustSound.start();
            fuel -= 0.5;
            fuelGauge.setProgress((int)fuel);
            }
       }
       else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

          mThrustSound.pause();
          //mThrustSound.release();   
       }
       else{
          //do nothing
       }
          return true;
       }
   });
  ```

Comment: Are you sure that the `else if` part is not executed? Did you try to put a `Log` inside and check?

Comment: yeah the else if is executed as when i let go of the button (ACTION_UP) the sound effects being used stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation makes this reasonably clear:

> On pointing devices with source class SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER such as touch screens, the pointer coordinates specify absolute positions such as view X/Y coordinates. Each complete gesture is represented by a sequence of motion events with actions that describe pointer state transitions and movements. A gesture starts with a motion event with ACTION_DOWN that provides the location of the first pointer down. As each additional pointer that goes down or up, the framework will generate a motion event with ACTION_POINTER_DOWN or ACTION_POINTER_UP accordingly. Pointer movements are described by motion events with ACTION_MOVE. Finally, a gesture end either when the final pointer goes up as represented by a motion event with ACTION_UP or when gesture is canceled with ACTION_CANCEL.

So you should *expect* to get a single `ACTION_DOWN` event, followed by multiple `ACTION_MOVE` events. It sounds like basically you need to respond to `ACTION_MOVE` as well if you want to handle movements, and if you want to do something *continuously* while the touch takes place, you probably want some kind of timer event (as you won't be generating new motion events - there's no *motion* involved in just touching and holding).

Comment: okay so if i understand this correctly there will be no repeating or looping of the ACTION_DOWN event becuase it is only an event that happens once, not an event that repeats WHILE ACTION_DOWN. So to get around this i can setup a handler with a timer

Comment: @ChrisHill: Yes, I believe that's the case.